# Populating Navigation Tabs with SQL?

Tags: php, navigation, auto-populate

I'm looking for some kind of Nav tab (vertical) that allows it to be populated by SQL. For example, in the SQL table there would be a column for title (which is the title of the tab) and a column for the contents of the tab.

I have tried building one myself, but I have no idea how to fit it in a nav bar because usually I'd do a while loop to populate something with SQL, but because nav's have two things that need populating (the `<li>` and the `<div>` bits), I am unsure of how to do it.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
    <ul>
<?php
    $query = tep_db_query("select * table1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<li><a href="#tabs-' . $row['tabid'] . '">' . $row['tabtitle'] . '</a></li>'
    }
    ?>

    </ul>




<?php
    $query2 = tep_db_query("select * table1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    echo '
    <div id="tabs-' . $row['tabid'] . '">

    <p> ' . $row['tabcontent'] . ' </p>
    '
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you please post some of your code so we understand your approach a little better?

Comment: Edited my topic. In theory, would it work like that?

Comment: I've added the `php` tag for you so that you can get some better attention for your question. Don't mind my OCD : )

Comment: did you try using jquery and updating both places from the same file? ajaxly like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have seems like it would be okay, you might be able to do something like this in order to eliminate half of your db calls.

```
//Get information from db.
<?php
    $query = tep_db_query("SELECT tabid, tabtitle, tabcontent FROM table1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $table[] = $row;
    }
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach($table as $row){
    echo '<li><a href="#tabs-' . $row['tabid'] . '">' . $row['tabtitle'] . '</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>

<?php foreach($table as $row){
    echo '
    <div id="tabs-' . $row['tabid'] . '">

    <p> ' . $row['tabcontent'] . ' </p>
    ';
}
?>
```